# How to check which option is selected in multi-select dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Well options are listed based on `ng-repeat` value in dropdown, using AngualrJS. How can I know which option is selected in a multi-select dropdown like this one:

```
<select custom-select ng-model="selectedEmp" data-container="body" multiple="">
    <option value="{{ emp._id }}" ng-repeat="emp in employeeList">
        {{ emp.first_name }} {{ emp.last_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. It is said here that if multiple is set then "Allows multiple options to be selected. The selected values will be bound to the model as an array.". So look at the [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects). I think this is doing what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by following way

HTML

```
<select custom-select ng-model="selectedEmp" data-container="body" multiple="">
    <option  ng-repeat="emp in names" ng-click="getSelected()">
        {{ emp.Name }} {{ emp.Country }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.getSelected= function(){
  console.log($scope.selectedEmp)
}
```